# Bootstrap: ordered list with divs not aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, html

I'm using Bootstrap to create a website. I need to create an ordered list that has text then an image next to it. For some reason, the content of the list is shifted by one line so that it looks like this:

```
1. 
  text here [ image here ]
2.
  text here  [ image here ]
```

How do I get it to align properly?

here is my code:

```
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="span6">Test</div>
                            <div class="span6"><img src="asdfd.png"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="span6">Test</div>
                            <div class="span6"><img src="asdfds"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
```